# Xcode objective-c NSThread arguments

Tags: xcode, arguments, nsthread

I have a function that I need to run async in a separate thread however I couldn't figure out how to pass multiple arguments to the function so I decided to pass an array of arguments.

**There are two lines of code that I won't compile indicated with the comment `//PROBLEM WITH THE FOLLOWING LINE`.**

If I comment out those problem lines and run the application it actually runs and returns result for a second or two and then blows up an with Error dump. The error message is below and I also wanted to say that when I ran the same code on a different machine it returned the `NSException` as "Memory is Trashed" or something to that extent.

```
2015-07-17 15:49:44.807 SANSearch[6912:209007] (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f18c03c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8d19876e objc_exception_throw + 43
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f18beed +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
3   Foundation                          0x00007fff90162d57 -[NSRLEArray objectAtIndex:effectiveRange:] + 142
4   UIFoundation                        0x00007fff8e5119c4 -[NSLayoutManager removeTemporaryAttribute:forCharacterRange:] + 173
5   AppKit                              0x00007fff97622daa -[NSTextView _markForTextCheckingAfterChange] + 432
6   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f0a88ec __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
7   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f09a9f5 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
8   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f09a536 __CFRunLoopRun + 1814
9   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f099bd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
10  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff9656756f RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235
11  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff965672ea ReceiveNextEventCommon + 431
12  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff9656712b _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
13  AppKit                              0x00007fff973bf8ab _DPSNextEvent + 978
14  AppKit                              0x00007fff973bee58 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 346
15  AppKit                              0x00007fff973b4af3 -[NSApplication run] + 594
16  AppKit                              0x00007fff97331244 NSApplicationMain + 1832
17  SANSearch                           0x00000001000016d2 main + 34
18  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff8c6b75c9 start + 1
19  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
)
2015-07-17 15:49:44.829 SANSearch[6912:209182] An uncaught exception was raised
2015-07-17 15:49:44.830 SANSearch[6912:209182] NSMutableRLEArray replaceObjectsInRange:withObject:length:: Out of bounds
2015-07-17 15:49:44.830 SANSearch[6912:209182] (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f18c03c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8d19876e objc_exception_throw + 43
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f18beed +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
3   Foundation                          0x00007fff9017ca32 -[NSMutableRLEArray replaceObjectsInRange:withObject:length:] + 142
4   UIFoundation                        0x00007fff8e511a41 -[NSLayoutManager removeTemporaryAttribute:forCharacterRange:] + 298
5   AppKit                              0x00007fff9761bfad -[NSTextView _markTextEditedForRange:] + 1260
6   AppKit                              0x00007fff976132c4 -[NSTextView insertText:replacementRange:] + 3220
7   AppKit                              0x00007fff9775d871 -[NSTextView insertText:] + 318
8   SANSearch                           0x0000000100003856 -[AppDelegate doSearch:] + 1782
9   Foundation                          0x00007fff90181dc2 __NSThread__main__ + 1345
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff9bb1c268 _pthread_body + 131
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff9bb1c1e5 _pthread_body + 0
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff9bb1a41d thread_start + 13
)
2015-07-17 15:49:44.830 SANSearch[6912:209182] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 'NSMutableRLEArray replaceObjectsInRange:withObject:length:: Out of bounds'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f18c03c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8d19876e objc_exception_throw + 43
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f18beed +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
3   Foundation                          0x00007fff9017ca32 -[NSMutableRLEArray replaceObjectsInRange:withObject:length:] + 142
4   UIFoundation                        0x00007fff8e511a41 -[NSLayoutManager removeTemporaryAttribute:forCharacterRange:] + 298
5   AppKit                              0x00007fff9761bfad -[NSTextView _markTextEditedForRange:] + 1260
6   AppKit                              0x00007fff976132c4 -[NSTextView insertText:replacementRange:] + 3220
7   AppKit                              0x00007fff9775d871 -[NSTextView insertText:] + 318
8   SANSearch                           0x0000000100003856 -[AppDelegate doSearch:] + 1782
9   Foundation                          0x00007fff90181dc2 __NSThread__main__ + 1345
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff9bb1c268 _pthread_body + 131
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff9bb1c1e5 _pthread_body + 0
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff9bb1a41d thread_start + 13
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)buttonSearch_Click:(id)sender {
    //Clear the textView
    self.buttonSearchOutlet.enabled = false;
    [self.textViewOutlet selectAll:self];
    [self.textViewOutlet delete:nil];
    NSArray *words = [self.searchWordOutlet.stringValue componentsSeparatedByString: @" "];
    NSArray *arguments = @[directoryURL, words, self.textViewOutlet];
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(doSearch:) withObject:arguments];
    self.buttonSearchOutlet.enabled = true;
}

//This is the function I wish to run in a thread    
-(void)doSearch:(NSArray *) parameters{
    //void doSearch(NSArray *parameters){
    //PROBLEM WITH THE FOLLOWING LINE - 'NSAutoreleasePool' IS NOT AVAILABLE IN AUTOMAIC REFERENCE COUNTING MODE
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSURL *searchPathURL = parameters[0];
    NSArray *searchWords = parameters[1];
    NSTextView *resultsTextView = parameters[2];
    //void doSearch(NSURL *searchPathURL, NSArray *searchWords, NSTextView *textView){
    NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    NSURLIsDirectoryKey, NSURLIsPackageKey, NSURLLocalizedNameKey, nil];
    NSDirectoryEnumerator *enumerator = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
    enumeratorAtURL:searchPathURL
    includingPropertiesForKeys:keys
    options:(NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles)
    errorHandler:^(NSURL *url, NSError *error) {
    // Handle the error.
    // Return YES if the enumeration should continue after the error.
    return YES;
}
];

for (NSURL *url in enumerator) {
    // Error-checking is omitted for clarity.

    NSNumber *isDirectory = nil;
    [url getResourceValue:&isDirectory forKey:NSURLIsDirectoryKey error:NULL];

    if ([isDirectory boolValue]) {
        NSString *localizedName = nil;
        [url getResourceValue:&localizedName forKey:NSURLLocalizedNameKey error:NULL];

        NSNumber *isPackage = nil;
        [url getResourceValue:&isPackage forKey:NSURLIsPackageKey error:NULL];

        if ([isPackage boolValue]) {
            //Its a package
            //NSLog(@"Package at %@", localizedName);
        } else {
            //Its a directory
            //NSLog(@"Directory at %@", localizedName);
    }
} else {
    //Its a file
    NSString *searchPath = [url.path lowercaseString];
    for (NSString *searchWord in searchWords ){
        NSString *searchText = [searchWord lowercaseString];
        if ([searchPath containsString:searchText]) {
            NSLog(@"%@", url.path);
            //[textView insertText:url.path];
            //[textView insertText:@"\n"];
            [resultsTextView insertText:url.path];
            [resultsTextView insertText:@"\n"];
        }
    }
}
}
//PROBLEM WITH THE FOLLOWING LINE - 'release' IS NOT AVAILABLE IN AUTOMAIC REFERENCE COUNTING MODE
[pool release];
}
```

Comment: You solve this problem?